# DAX measure to extract summed quantity values for selected weeks only

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have production figures which sum the quantity of parts produced by each workstation on a weekly basis. These are shown in a matrix with workstation number on the rows and week numbers across the columns.

I want to be able to select 2 weeks and then

- Display all the weeks in the range selected by a slicer.
- Show the quantity values for only the first and last selected weeks.

The first part is working using a simple Week Slicer.
The second part, however, always shows the totals for all the selected weeks rather than the 2 individual week quantities.

In this example I have selected weeks 4 and 9 and therefore the expected values for quantities are 11,505 and 49,425 as shown in the Good Qty data with red frames.

[image: Data]

The measures to extract the fist and last selected week numbers are working:

```
SelWeek1 = FIRSTNONBLANK(VALUES(vLink[Week]),0)

SelWeek2 = LASTNONBLANK(VALUES(vLink[Week]),0)
```

My measures for the week quantities are:

```
IF([SelWeek1]>0,  
    CALCULATE([Sum vGood Qty],FILTER(vLink, vLink[Week] = [SelWeek1])),  
    0
)  

and

SelWeek2 Qty = 
IF([SelWeek2]>0,
    CALCULATE([Sum vGood Qty],FILTER(vLink, vLink[Week] = [SelWeek2])),
    0
)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below measures:

```
SelWeek1 = MIN(vLink[week])
```

```
Measure =
VAR _selWeek = [SelWeek1]
VAR result = 
CALCULATE(
   [Sum vGood Qty], 
   vLink[Week] = _selWeek
)
RETURN
  result
```

and for selected week 2 change min to max in the first measure and _selWeek variable in the second measure respectively.

Comment: Thank you, that works - and also eliminates a filter.  However, if I replace the selWeek variable and use [SelWeek1] in the CALCULATE it is invalid DAX.  
 

**QtyWeek1 = CALCULATE([Sum vGood Qty], vLink[Week] = [SelWeek1])**


_A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed._

**So why does this scenario require putting [SelWeek1] into a variable first?**